# Build system with integrated tools

Tags: c#, c++, build, msbuild

How would one go about creating/using existing build systems with integrated build tools.

Example:
Need to build c# or C++ or C.  Some projects are only MS based, other projects/solutions are Linux based.

If I wanted to bring in a new developer or setup another build machine, I could automatically get the build tools for a specific project (maybe in a configuration somewhere list dependency build tools), and download the source.  There would be automatic scripts that set the paths to the downloaded build tools so you could either make/cmake/msbuild the project with the tools downloaded from the build system itself.

I have seen this at one time, but have been looking for it and not seeing it again.

Comment: Is using a bunch of virtual machines on a server acceptable?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm reading your question right, but couldn't you just set up one machine, and then copy the partition to any new machine? or maybe you should look into how to set environment variables so that your scripts can find the build tools they need: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable

Comment: Actually the plan was to be able to spin up a VM, create a build environment, download source from the repository, build and then blow away the VM.  My first thought was to setup a remote repository that contained all the build tools and scripts that setup the path and Environment variables, but I thought there might be limitations there.  For example, any dependencies needed have to be downloaded off the network.  This will slow down building significantly.

Comment: So couldn't you just put all the installers for any required build tools into a folder, and write a batch file that will install them all? If you needed more control, you could use a win32 console application. CreateProcess() to run the installer, and WaitForSingleObject() to wait until it's finished. You could also check the windows registry for build tools that are already installed. The whole bundle could be contained in a single downloadable zip file...so all anyone would have to do is download, extract, and run your script/console app.

Comment: Want to be linux and windows capable.  Also it will be a portable build environment, so no installers.  All SDKs, and other dependencies need to be housed in the build tools.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understood your question completetly but by using what I understood I can recommend you to try http://cosmos.codeplex.com/ <- a c# operating system development package. Or for linux try http://www.linuxfromscratch.org <- this helps us to build another linux by using preinstalled linux integrated tools.